# Ignore the double quotes using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have the following code in `awk`

```
awk -F"[.: ]" '/Backing up \"/1/2\" on One/ {start = mktime($3" "$2" "$1" "$4" "$5" "$6); hms = sprintf("%s:%s:%s,", $4, $5, $6);} / Backup completed/ {end = mktime($3" "$2" "$1" "$4" "$5" "$6); if (end) {print hms end - start; start = ""; }}' logs.txt
```

I want to search for the pattern `Backing up "/1/2" on One` and display the following message .

I am getting the output for the following code as below. How do I ignore double quotes and search the pattern .

> backslash not last character on line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex inside the `awk` command is incorrect.

You need to add a backslash `\` before the (forward) slash `/` because this character is the regex delimiter:

```
awk '/Backing up "\/1\/2" on One/{...}'
```

Note that you don't need to add a backslash before the double quote because the shell won't interpret the string inside single quote.